# How to handle undetermined number of arguments?

Tags: php, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a procedure which works like this:

```
$e = "name,Alan,Georges,Edith,Julia,Donna,Bernard,Christophe,Salvatore,Laure,Thomas";
$f = explode("," ,$e);
if (function_exists($f[0])) {
$f[0]($f[1], $f[2], $f[3], $f[4], $f[5], $f[6], $f[7], $f[8], $f[9], $f[10]);
}
```

Can I handle this more elegantly?
I mean, can I handle for example 30 parameters without writing :

```
$f[0]($f[1], $f[2], $f[3], ..., ..., $f[26], $f[27], $f[28], $f[29], $f[30]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func_array()` to pass parameters via array:

```
$f = ['foo', 'param1', 'param2'];
$func = array_shift($f); // remove function name.
call_user_func_array($func, $f);
```

(use the above example code with the function below...)

To obtain an arbitrary list of function arguments, use `func_get_args()`

```
function foo() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    print_r($args);
}
```

You'd not even have to specifiy the arguments, just pass as many as you want:

```
foo(1, 2, 4, 'hello', 1.234, ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Produces the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => hello
    [4] => 1.234
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )

)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array

Hope that helps